# Java DB SQLite - link tables

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

My question might be really straightforward to answer, but i need one or two tips from you...

I have created two tables in SQLite and I would like to create a 3rd one based on these two. Basically the 3rd one will store the results calculated from elements of the two tables.

Simply, assuming my first table (in column) is

```
A
B
C
```

and my second

```
a
b
c
```

I would like to tell SQlite that an element i of my 3rd table is the result of the calculation between two elements of the initial tables and therefore link it to these two elements - for example:

```
i1 = void(A,b)
i2 = void(C,a)
etc...
```

I am pretty sure that I have to use the indexes of my two tables and possibly the command "join" but i'm struggling with the syntax which is different in Java DB.

I might spend a lot of time on this.

Answer (score 0):

First you'll have to [create these three tables in SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp). Then learn how to [insert data](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) into the third table. Then, you can learn how to [insert data from another table using a select statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php). Joins are not that hard as you'll see in [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). At the end perform the calculation using [SQL operators and functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_functions.asp).

Comment: Thanks mate for your help - I had read these tutorials but could not figure out how to apply the concepts to my specific case

Comment: You are welcome. What's the nature of the calculation used to fill the third column?